# C++ Linux - Is creating new threads expensive?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have started developing applications on my Raspberry Pi and am designing a server to be as efficient as possible with the given resources, so my question is spawning new threads as expensive as it is on Windows? (I know on Windows they have a thread pool, which is more efficient than creating a new thread) But is it the same for Linux?

I am using EPoll to get events about if someone new connected/wrote to me/etc and want to spawn worker threads for each request to handle the data while keeping the main thread free.

Is it possible to spawn multiple threads and have them get suspended after executing then wait for new input etc? That way it would cut out the spawn time of creating new threads.

Comment: Who they (who have the thread pool)? What is expensive for you, do you want to create 10 threads per second, 1000 or 100000 per second? How much work will be done by thread?

Comment: @osgx , sorry about that I just edited my post. But as many requests as I get so I would say around the ballpark of 500 per second. As for the work, it will read the input, parse for any commands, and text to all other connected clients (a chat server basically).

Comment: Create a thread pool *if* needed. Use synchronization primitives for the waiting. Doubt there's anything more to discuss here....

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thanks, I haven't messed around with multithreading much so I appreciate all the input.

Comment: starting threads have a cost; "expensive" is relative. It is more efficient to use dedicated worker threads than to create a new thread per operation

Comment: Well, mess around....

Comment: As I know, both kinds of OS will do some work when application creates thread. And thread pool is the implementation of your application (your server): start several threads, and pass clients to them. When one client is done, thread check some shared structure and go to sleep on some mutex/cond variable to wait next client. Spawning and destroying thread per user request is easier to write and will work for low number of requests per second. And with 500 req/s you will get problems from slow CPU, low number of cores, overhead of context switching... Do some experiments and measure.

Comment: Have you considered using the asio framework or similat? Spawning a new thread for each request is usually a bad idea.